# Context free Grammar for this context free language

Tags: regular-languages, context-free

How can I create a context free grammar for the language $\{p^2q^mpr^nq^{2n+m}| m,n \ge 0\}$, where $\Sigma = \{p,q,r\}$?

Comment: We discourage "please check whether my answer is correct" questions, as only "yes/no" answers are possible, which won't help you or future visitors. See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/519/). Can you edit your post to ask about a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about? As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on. If you just need someone to check your work, you might seek out a friend, classmate, or teacher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When trying to come up with a grammer for this language, there are several things one must make sure every word generated by it satisfies, including:

1. It starts with a double $p$
2. Every addition of a $q$ that comes before the middle $p$ also adds a $q$ at the end
3. Every addition of an $r$ after the middle $p$ also adds 2 $q$'s  at the end
4. There is only a single middle $p$ between the $q$'s and the $r$'s

Your answer satisfies condition 1, but mixes up 2 &3 and violates 4. Therefore, my corrections to it result in the following grammer:
$$S\rightarrow ppA$$
$$A\rightarrow qAq|pB$$
$$B\rightarrow rBqq|\varepsilon$$
Also, be careful with mixing up lowercase and uppercase letters!

Comment: Maybe you could add some explanation or method that helped you to create this grammar? Besides, giving straight answer to homework question may cause some harm in the learning process.

Comment: Fair enough, I edited my answer, even though the writer didn't specify this was homework. The reason I didn't add an explanation at first is that before answering the question myself, I commented on the writer's own answer, letting him know what he got wrong. He was already close.

Comment: thanks a lot man, one of the people who was actually helpful rather than just tell me what im doing wrong, appreciate the help and it wasnt homework :)

Comment: You're welcome, but other people were also trying to help you in the long run by letting you know how to properly ask questions here, so that more people will want to answer them (:
 If this answer is helpful to you and solves your problem, you can "accept" it, as specified here:
https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: I think the answer is incorrect as it includes an extra q, when i use the grammar to create a parse tree for a string derived from the language it comes up with an extra q

Comment: Do you have a specific example?

Comment: okay so by my understanding your grammar reads ppqprqqq, there's an extra q if we take the example string, ppqqprqqqq with m being 2 and n = 0 when using your grammar to create the parse tree we end up with an extra q

Comment: @DeanGurvitz I would show it drawn out but i dont know how i would upload it

Comment: You are right, I mixed up $n$ and $m$. I will fix it.

Answer (score -1):

I've come up with

$$
\begin{align}  
 S&\rightarrow PPX  \\                                                                         
 X&\rightarrow QXQQ\mid Y \\                                                                                                                
 Y&\rightarrow PYR\mid \epsilon
\end{align}
$$

Comment: First of all, you need to be careful with mixing up lowercase and uppercase letters. In addition,  your answer is incorrect because of Y's transition, which can generate many p's in between the q's and the r's, and doesn't add a "q" for each added "r"